# html search bar with results displaying incorrectly (shifted to the right)

Tags: html, css

I have a simple search bar with results that should display directly under it and overflow only in the y-direction. However, the results are shifted to the right and it overflows in the x-direction also. What would be a simple fix for this?

https://jsfiddle.net/aw1ofzcz/

My html is:

```
<div id="msearchAndResult">
              <input type="text" maxLength="20" placeholder=" Search" id="msearchField">
              <ul id="mresultsList">    
                  <li class="searchres">item and or some other long text that should wrap around</li>
                  <li class="searchres">item</li>
                  <li class="searchres">item</li>
                  <li class="searchres">item</li>
              </ul>
    Other content <br>content<br>content<br>
content                  
            </div>
```

And the css is:

```
#msearchField{
padding: 2px;
border: 2px solid #BEBEBE;
width: 140px;
height: 25px;
display: block;
border-radius: 7%;
background: url("/images/search_lens.jpg") no-repeat right center;
background-size: 18%;
}

#msearchAndResult {
margin-bottom: 10px;
margin-top: 1%;
width: 140px;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
}

#mresultsList {
position: absolute;
list-style-type: none;
z-index: 5;
max-height: 110px;
overflow-y: auto;
}

.searchres {
word-wrap: break-word;
font-size: 120%;
background-color: #F5FFFA;
width: 126px;
border: 2px solid grey;
}
```

Comment: is this what you're looking for? https://jsfiddle.net/aw1ofzcz/5/

Comment: In terms of appearance yes, but I don't understand why it would go to the right. Also, it should appear on top of other content, so I think position: relative; wont work for the list

Comment: well is the 'othercontent' something you have control over? I moved it outside of the msearchAndResult div. There are a couple different ways to handle this

Comment: and its going  'to the right' because your using and unordered list, and those are 'list items' that are indented naturally.

Comment: No, i don't have control other other content. Ok i have removed the padding, however, there still remains a gap between the search bar and results

Comment: Fixed everything, thank you for the help

Answer (score 0):

Removed list padding and margin and making list wider fixed the problems

https://jsfiddle.net/aw1ofzcz/

```
#mresultsList {
position: absolute;
list-style-type: none;
z-index: 5;
max-height: 110px;
overflow-y: auto;
    padding: 0;
    width: 162px;
    margin: 0;
}
```